# Flutter BackDrop filter not working in IOS device

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, flutter-ios

In android device backdrop filter working well but in IOS device background not be blur.

```
 Widget commonBottomButton(String imagePath) {
return ClipOval(
  child: BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(
      sigmaX: 50.0,
      sigmaY: 50.0,
    ),
    child: Container(
      height: 100.w,
      width: 100.w,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        // color: AppColors.goldColor
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Image.asset(
          imagePath,
          package: Core.corePackage,
          width: 52.w,
          height: 52.h,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
Thanks in advance